How can I download PyTorch packages from a specific index URL using IDM or similar tool due to unstable network?
Due to my unstable network, I'm unable to reliably use pip to download PyTorch packages (torch, torchvision, torchaudio) from the PyTorch download page (https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121). Manually downloading each file isn't feasible due to the large number of files. Could someone advise me on how to automate this download process using IDM (Internet Download Manager) or another tool that supports resumable downloads? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
